# azure drive storage and map drive

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there any way to create a drive in windows azure, and then that the users at the company can map a drive in their windows explorer, and upload documents there?

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought you could do that through `Azure File Service` announced recently but then I found out that you can only mount in the VMs running in the same region as the storage account.

You may want to look at [`Gladinet Cloud Desktop`](http://www.gladinet.com/) tool which allows you to mount a blob storage account as a drive on the local computer. More information about this can be found here: http://www.gladinet.com/p/map_azure_storage_as_virtual_drive.htm.

Other than this, AFAIK there are no other ways to map a storage account as a drive on your local computer.